WiX installer with chaining uninstalling its child packages
I have a master installer bundle that calls other WiX installers. However on the uninstallation, I would like the uninstall operation to uninstall all of the child packages.
I am using a bootstrapper with a bundle. I am using a format like:
All of the other installers have this convention set up as well. However on the uninstall process, only the top level application is removed and not the other ones. How do I go about uninstalling items that are chained?
<ExePackage
     SourceFile="..\dir1\dir2\bin\Release\Master Bundle.exe"
     InstallCommand="/quiet" UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet" >
 </ExePackage>


You need to add a DetectCondition attribute. That will enable Burn to know that the package is installed and should be uninstalled. From the documentation:

DetectCondition (String) : A condition that determines if the package is present on the target system. This condition can use built-in variables and variables returned by searches. This condition is necessary because Windows doesn't provide a method to detect the presence of an ExePackage. Burn uses this condition to determine how to treat this package during a bundle action; for example, if this condition is false or omitted and the bundle is being installed, Burn will install this package.

In WiX v4+, you can use the BundlePackage element instead if your exe is a Burn bundle. That element automatically takes care of the detect condition.
